# Does scaling of the ordinal variables make sense before PCA?

Tags: pca, normalization

I have some data with 200+ variables/columns (30% numerical, 30% Likert 1-5 scale and 40% Likert 1-10 scale). I want to do principal component analysis (PCA) in R. I think I should scale the data before calling `psych::principal`.

My questions:

1. Is it correct to scale the data having both numerical and categorical variables?
2. Does scaling of categorical variables make sense?

I believe the answer is NO for both questions.

Comment: **Likert scale variables are not categorical!** They are ordinal.

Comment: Though we often assume even further that they are interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCA unfortunately only makes sense with numerical data.  For instance, if you have a variable that can take the values {'car', 'train', 'boat'}, it will be difficult to do arithmetic with them.  If we replace them with $\{0, 1, 2\}$, we can do arithmetic, but that arithmetic will really not achieve what we want, because we'll be treating these labels like real numbers.  As if (train + train = boat), or even train being closer to car than boat is.  However we have another option, to create *dummy variables*, one variable for each value that this categorical variable can take, setting them equal to 1 or 0 accordingly.

(Note: some people would use one less variable than the number of values, letting all 0 indicate the remaining variable, but geometrically this is troubling because the all-zero-variable is closer to all the other variables than they are to eachother, so I would not do that with PCA).

These values can be rescaled and PCA can be applied.  It may not be ideal, but at least it's not crazy!

**Edit:**

I had not noticed the word Likert in your post some how.  Likert scales are *ordinal*, rather than *categorical* variables.  In fact, typically one assumes Likert scales are *interval*, essentially meaning that the difference between 1 and 2 is the same as the difference between 4 and 5.  Because of this scale absolutely makes sense!  I have changed your title to use the word "ordinal" rather than "categorical."

Comment: These are valid points, but note that the OP is asking about variables on the Likert scale, which means they are *ordinal* and not really "categorical" (even though @Shiv called them like that). Arguable treating Likert scale variables like usual numerical variables would make some sense. Perhaps you want to expand your answer to discuss that?

Comment: @amoeba thanks a lot.  I hadn't seen that.  Since he used the word categorical, my brain kicked into speed.  I am going to edit the title.

Comment: Thank you @jlimahaverford and amoeba.
To summarize my understanding, scaling of Ordinal may make sense but not necessarily Categorical